# typeorm loads entities really slow

Tags: typeorm

We use typeorm in our node.js application and it seems that loading the entities on startup is adding a significant amount of time. Or db schema is fairly small/simple however loading the application seems to take upwards of 2 minutes. If I pass an empty array (no entities) then the app loads significantly faster.

1. How can I enable logging in typeorm for initialization?
2. Is there a way to reduce loading times?

```
export const entities = [
  Account,
  Bundle,
  Category,
  Customer,
  Device,
  Event,
  EventMember,
  GoldrushMasterEvent,
  Order,
  Organization,
  OrganizationGroup,
  Province,
  Role,
  Ticket,
  TicketPackage,
  SalesReportView,
  User,
  SystemConfig,
  TicketDetailsView,
  EventMemberSalesView,
  Invoice,
  InvoiceItem,
  InvoiceItemCode,
  EventSalesView,
  OrderDetailsView
];

export interface DatabaseConnectionOptions {
  connectionName?: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  host: string;
  port: number;
  database: string;
  maxPoolSize: number;
}

/**
 * Uses type orm to connect to the RDS instance
 *
 * @param options
 */
const connectDatabase = async (options: DatabaseConnectionOptions): Promise<void> => {
  const dbConfig: ConnectionOptions = {
    name: options.connectionName,
    type: 'postgres',
    schema: 'public',
    entities: entities,
    synchronize: false,
    logging: process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true',
    logger: 'advanced-console',
    username: options.username,
    password: options.password,
    host: options.host,
    port: options.port,
    database: options.database,
    extra: {
      max: options.maxPoolSize
    },
    // log anything that takes more than a second
    maxQueryExecutionTime: 1000
  };

  await createConnection(dbConfig);
};
```

Comment: Noticing slow boot of TypeORM with Postgres generally (i.e. often around 2s, always at least close to 1s) even with no entities and logging. Not seeing nearly as long as a minute or 2, but also looking for answers.